# Trello tab updates are not pushed MS Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

All of you know the Trello-Slack integration app, which lets Trello board changes being immediately pushed to Slack channel.

How about the same support in Teams for Trello tabs added to the channel?
It is really difficult to keep track of tasks only by accessing the tab.

Card changes, card transfer/deletion/assignment notifications support would be priceless.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a really feature request and not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that Teams supports Connectors for it's channels. There was a corresponding one for Trello.

Comment: Yes, that was the workaround I was going to suggest - glad you found it.